# Raphael setting the attr of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

I am using raphaeljs add need to set attributes on an element, however the attributes name and value are saved in variables

```
var attr_name='fill'; 
var attr_value='#343434';
```

but the following does not work

```
exampleelement.attr({attr_name: attr_value});
```

however if I type in the actual name in the attr field it works

```
exampleelement.attr({'fill': attr_value});
```

I have tried wrapping it in quotes and double quotes but this has no effect.

Please can anyone suggest anything? 
It is not really an option to manually type them in as this code runs in a loop and each time it could be a different attribute it is setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
exampleelement.attr(attr_name, attr_value);
```

jQuery Docs -  [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Mark it as answer if its helpful :)

Comment: @Baadshah he/she need's to wait for the Timer :D

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is

```
exampleelement.attr(key, val);
```

Answer (score 0):

what I found is:

```
exampleelement.attr({fill:'#343434'});
```

or

```
exampleelement.attr('fill': '#343434');
```

both are same.

Note: There is --> {} <-- in first one.